# Reducing the noise made by pinecones landing on my roof

Tags: roof, noise-reduction

The back half of my house has a flat roof. Dozens of feet above this roof hangs a tree. This tree drops pinecones. The sound of these pinecones hitting my roof at speed is very loud.

Is there something practical I can do to the roof to reduce the amount of noise?

As its flat I was thinking maybe there's some kind of exterior insulation sheets I could apply to the roof.

Let's assume I can't remove or prune the tree.

Comment: You had to add that last line didn't you to take the fun out of answering.  There are rubberize roof membranes that can be added to the roof.  More expensive would be a roof shade/second roof air gaped.  Cheapest would be ear plugs.

Comment: A large net might work?

Comment: If it's a flat roof, I really like the idea of putting a sunshade above it and some wear-prevention decking on it, adding a door, and calling it a patio. Maybe even put greenhouse walls around it.

Comment: About six inches of pine needles should do it.

Comment: Removing the tree is probably the best course of action. It appears to be far too close to the house for the house's safety (roots and falling specifically).

Comment: @keshlam If even modest winds are present, they will necessitate a quite robust sunshade. The net idea mostly avoids this issue.

Comment: Lots of vented sunshades exist. Lots of decks with translucent fiberglass panel roofing exist. No, it isn't trivial, but "If it happens, it must be possible." And I seriously dislike flat roofs unless there is a reason no alternative is possible, but that's my own bias.